# How to create variable number of using scopes?

Tags: c#

This code does not actually work as _next will be called with each iteration.  Just wanted to give an outline of what I am trying to accomplish.  I need to create a variable number of using statements that then exist for following statement which should be called exactly once.  Any ideas?

```
//Values For Headers to Log Actually to Come From Config
var headers = new List<string>() {"transactionid", "ipaddress", "somecustomeheader"};

foreach (var header in headers)
using (contextCorrelator.BeginLoggingCorrelationScope(header,
           GetHeaderValue(header)))
{
    //if iteration == headers.count then
    await _next(httpContext);  //Need this to only be called once....BUT, I need all of the headers to have a scope added in a using statement that still exist before it is called.
}
```

Comment: I don't think `using` is the correct tool for the job, here.

Comment: me neither... a `using`-statement is a compiler-feature that is more or less identical to a try/finally-block. There is no concept of runtime-blocks. Why do you dynamically want to add such statements at all?

Answer (score 1):

**If** I am understanding correctly, then I doubt that `using` is really helpful here. I think, what you may be wanting is something like this:

```
var disposables = new List<IDisposable>();

foreach(var header in headers)
{
    disposables.Add((IDisposable) contextCorrelator.BeginLoggingCorrelationScope(header,
           GetHeaderValue(header)));
}

try
{
     await _next(httpContext);
}
finally
{
    foreach( var disp in disposables )
    {
        disp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct.  The using statement does not work in the pseudo code I gave.  Was just trying to get the idea across.  I think your solution will work.  Was just hoping to avoid the extra code of tracking the disposables like how the using statement provides.  I'm thinking it is not possible but wanted to see if someone had thought of a way.